# Prevent window from minimizing

Tags: vb.net

I have a bit of code here that ask the user to first close a window he opened earlier before opening another or tell the user that the window he wants to open is already opened.
I would the opened form to stay opened and not be minimized when its opened.

```
Private Sub FindClientToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FindClientToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Close items form
    Dim Close_items As New Form_items

    'Call find client form when clicking tab Find client
    Dim ShowFindClient As New Find_Client

    'If the find_items form or window is opened, then a message prompts the user to close it first 
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Form_items).Any Then
        playErrorSound()
        MsgBox("Close Find_items window first", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "MDCS")

        'If find_clients form is opened. the user can not open it twice.
    ElseIf Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Find_Client).Any Then
         playErrorSound()
        MsgBox("The Window is already opened", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "MDCS")

    Else
        'If the find_client window is not opened, it opens.
        ShowFindClient.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Me.MinimizeBox = False` in your condition, you can disable it in form load as follows:

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MinimizeBox = False
End Sub
```

Comment: May I have a code that maximizes the window when try to open it while minimized?

Comment: @Hfirst It is bad manners while your question is answered to ask another one without marking it as answered first.